# How to add value in an array with function

Tags: javascript, function

```
var dictionary = {"val1": ["arr1", "arr2"], "val2": ["arr3", "arr4"]}

var addNew = ["arr5", "arr6"]
dictionary["Val3"] = AddNew
```

I would like to write a function to add another arr value into an array. For example: `"val1": ["arr1", "arr2", "arr7]`

But whatever I tried it's not working. I am new and I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: _But whatever I tried it's not working_ Post it and let us help you...

Comment: Did you try `dictionary.val1.push("arr7")`

Comment: from what you've posted: `dictionary.val1.push("arra7")` and `dictionary.val3 = addNew` (not AddNew) should do what you want.

Comment: Should be a simple push or concat.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this for add a property to the object

```
var dictionary = {
"val1": ["arr1", "arr2"], 
"val2": ["arr3", "arr4"]
}
var add =  function(prop, arr){
dictionary[prop].push(arr);
```

}

```
add("val2", "arr5");
```

/////////////////////////////

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
dictionary.val1.push("arr7");
```

---

`addNew` is not `AddNew`; `val3` is not `Val3`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much, my friend. As I told I am new and sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=b) function to add new elements to the end of the relevant array :

```
var dictionary = {"val1": ["arr1", "arr2"], "val2": ["arr3", "arr4"]}

var addNew = ["arr5", "arr6"]
dictionary["val1"] = dictionary["val1"].concat(addNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I guessed right what you wanna add an array under new PROPERTY of OBJECT, not into ARRAY

```
function (targetObject, propertyName, newArray){
    targetObject[propertyName] = newArray;
}
```

Or you wanna add inside existing PROPERTY of OBJECT?

```
function(targetObject, targetProperty, newArrayToAdd){
    Array.concat[targetObject[targetProperty], newArrayToAdd]    
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: PropertyName is not defined` - be careful with case. It's also a bit pointless to wrap a basic language feature (`obj[prop] = val`) into a function.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that from directly here, typo;) He asked for a function that does that I delivered. I didn't question was it a good point to do so.